# Are languages generated from a statically typed language statically typed?

Tags: type-theory, type-checking

Are languages generated from a statically typed language statically typed?

So say, generating Python from C++.

*to generate a language from another language:*

You write a *transpiler* in a static language $L_s$ so that it can produce the equivalent program in language $L_{sORd}$.

---

Issues:

- The statically typed language must be well-typed so it should not necessarily contain ways to express dynamic types.
- One may be able to emulate dynamic types by using some switches. However, are programs written for such dynamically or statically typed?

Comment: What do you mean by "languages generated from..."?  Please [edit] your post to explain in more detail what you are talking about.  Are you referring to a compiler that compiles from one language to another?  If so, are you asking about the case where the input language is statically typed, or where the compiler is written in a statically typed language?

Comment: I'm confused by your two issues. Those would be issues if you're transpiling from a dynamically typed language to a statically typed one. But in your main question you ask about transpiling from a statically typed language to a dynamically typed one, which is the other way around. So which way do you really mean?

Comment: Also, you might be interested in this blog post: [Dynamic Languages are Static Languages](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/dynamic-languages-are-static-languages/) and related questions like https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18847/139814

Comment: @Noughtmare Generating from a static backend language, because I think it's better to write using that.

Comment: There are three languages involved: (1) the (meta) language that implements the translation, (2) the source language of the translation, and (3) the target language of the translation. When you say "generating from" I get the feeling you mean (1), but I don't think (1) is actually relevant in this discussion, because you can implement the transpiler using any general purpose language. But maybe I'm misinterpreting things. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @Noughtmare Well e.g. have the application's source in C++, write a transpiler in C++, want as output an equivalent JS program that does not depend on the C++ code. Now is this JS program statically typed?

Comment: I think it depends on how you define what a statically typed program is. Practically JS will still do dynamic type checks when you run the program. But if you have type checked the C++ program and the transpiler is correct, then you could theoretically omit all dynamic type checks.

Comment: @Noughtmare Yes so then the JS program is statically typed.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not.

A C compiler typically compiles to machine code, which is not statically typed. While machine code is not really a programming language, this should be enough to convince you that the language the compiler compiles to doesn't need to be statically typed, or typed at all.

Examples:

- C compilers often compile to assembly language, which is then assembled into machine code. The types that C can statically check (such as integers and characters) do not exist in assembly language or machine code. Assembly language is not statically typed.
- [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) is a statically typed variant of JavaScript (which isn't statically typed). TypeScript is typically executed by compiling it to JavaScript and then executing the resulting JavaScript code (either by interpreting it or by compiling it and executing the result).
- C can be compiled to JavaScript; see e.g. [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/14q4dk/c_compiler_in_javascript_does_anybody_know_one/).

Comment: Isn't this a theoretical answer? I wasn't asking for a "for all" proof tbh. But whether a static source language can guarantee a static program at the target.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask that, but I do not see how to read that in the question as stated now. The answer is basically the same. You can translate to any kind of language you want. There is no relationship between whether the source language is statically typed and whether the target language is. Of course, if the languages are very close it may be possible to map the types onto each other.

Comment: In this case I think you're wrong. Yes, C compiles to machine code, which is not as whole statically typed. However, if we compiled a statically typed program (that uses a statically typed sublanguage), then is the resulting binary statically typed? It must be, if it's the same program?

Comment: No. A binary is not statically typed. Being statically typed means type violations can be detected in the source code, at compile time, rather than at execution time. Binaries aren't typically type checked at all and they may not have types to check in the first place. Web Assembly code has types, but what are the types of x86 machine language?

Comment: I just added two more examples.

Comment: Okay, well binary isn't statically typed, but then it's a program that doesn't have a type error? And so are all other compilations as long as they're translations of a statically typed program? So e.g. the JavaScript that a TypeScript program is compiled to is statically typed?

Comment: No, it is not. The types are a property of the language, not of the program.

Comment: The types have a binary representation? This is a bit above my experience, but isn't it technically possible to know what language a binary originates form by identifying e.g. types in the binary stream? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast

Comment: No, it is not. C++ types exist at compile time, not at runtime. `std::bit_cast` is compiled into code that will manipulate values in memory at runtime. That code will just manipulate values, it does not have any representations of types to work with.